# InvalidAttrNameOrValue response from SAML request

Tags: xml

I connect with a saml message to a portal.
When i try make logout with other saml message, the portal send me one error in your saml response.

error:

```
<Status>
    <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied" />
    </StatusCode>
    <StatusMessage>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied (urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidAttrNameOrValue)</StatusMessage>
</Status>
```

My message xml:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest 
                 xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                 xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:logout:user"
                 Destination="www.portal..."
                 ID="_09aee7ce288a1098759c97f309416fd631b396c5"
                 IssueInstant="2013-04-30T16:23:45"
                 Version="2.0"
                 >
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">issuer</saml:Issuer>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
        <Reference URI="#_09aee7ce288a1098759c97f309416fd631b396c5">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                         PrefixList="#default samlp saml ds xs xsi"
                                         />
                </Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>I8Q8151FOHeyi1hB+Gfs0YrfCaA=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>......</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
        <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>......</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
             xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
             >urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
</saml:NameID>  
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

help me to found error in my saml message please :)

Answer (score 1):

your sample xml lacks the closing tag for the root element: `</samlp:LogoutRequest>`.

Comment: sorry this tag miss in text but i have closing tag, other option?

Comment: any help? i tried many other things but never resulted, i dont understand my error in saml message.